# spring boot usage of placeholder in application properties

Tags: mysql, docker, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have written a simple spring boot application(version springboot 2.0) which uses mysql(version 5.7).

**application.properties** snippet

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = testuser
spring.datasource.password = testpassword
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

When I run it locally, it works fine.
If I want to run this spring boot application in docker then I can change

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/test?useSSL=false
```

*mysql-container is run using mysql:5.7 image from dockerhub.*

However I want to change value of host from some placeholder properties file. so that this looks something like:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:3306/test?useSSL=false
```

note: I am not sure about placeholder format. Is it ${MYSQL_HOST} or @MYSQL_HOST@ ?

you can name this placeholder file as *placeholder.properties* or *placeholder.conf* or *.env* or anything. The content of that file should be something like:

```
MYSQL_HOST=localhost
```

or

```
MYSQL_HOST=some ip address
```

I can create .env or .env.test or .env.prod and I can refer that env file based on where I want to run application.

---

UPDATE -

I have two questions:

1. Where should I keep placeholder.properties? Is it under /config/ or under some specific directory?
2. how to invoke placeholder inside application.properties ?

can someone suggest?

Comment: I used place Holder in application.properties like ${environment_prefix} you can try this it will work.

Comment: I tried ${MYSQL_HOST}, but that didn't work. Where exactly I should keep placeholder.properties file? check updated description.

Comment: Please see answer posted. Your suggestion definitely helped.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to answers by @Raheela Aslam and @paulsm4 and some more research found the issue.

What I was trying to achieve:

1. Deploy springboot application in docker and then to kubernetes.
2. I was using minikube for local testing and wanted to pass minikube ip to datasource url.

How I fixed it:

I created configmap for mysql_user, mysql_password, mysql_host with respective values.

```
kubectl create configmap mysql-config \
--from-literal=mysql_user=testuser \
--from-literal=mysql_password=testuserpass \
--from-literal=mysql_user=$(minikube ip)
```

and used these inside application.properties something like below

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}:3306/test?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = ${MYSQL_USER}
spring.datasource.password = ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and then used configmap values in deployment.yaml for kubernetes.
Then did start service for deployment.

Comment: This is correct way of doing it. We can define these placeholder names in deployment.yaml file and then we can define the values in helm chart by referencing through `secretKeyRef` in deployment.yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

SUGGESTION: If you have a relatively small #/properties, why not just have a different application.properties file for each different environment?

You'd specify the environment at runtime with `-Dspring.profiles.active=myenv`.

Look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties).

PS:

To answer your specific question: the syntax is `${MYSQL_HOST}`

Comment: I don't have small # properties, its just a snippet from actual properties file. So using profile is not an option.

Comment: ${MYSQL_HOST} didn't work. I have updated description with 2 questions. See if you can suggest something.

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make myself clear. 1) you have LOTS of options (cited above) including [24. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and [Properties with Spring and Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring).  Please read these links; please post back with specific questions.  2) I'd STRONGLY suggest using application.properties (for your common properties) *AND* profile-specific.properties. Both links discuss how. 3) ${MYSQL_HOST} should work, if the variable is defined correctly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I had already gone thru these before posting the issue. I was trying to check if there is any simpler solution to this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: My suggestion *IS* "simple" ... at the Spring Boot level.  But the thing you failed to make clear in your question was that you wanted to configure the "profile" at the *Kubernetes* (Docker orchestration) level. "*.properties/profiles" is the best way to go for SpringBoot; "configmap" is a better way to go for Kubernetes;  I'm glad you found a solution, and thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you project is Maven you can use maven filter:

```
<build>
  <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/myfilter.properties</filter>
  </filters>
</build>
```

This generates the `/target/classes/application.properties` it has been filtered to contain the property values (with replaced placeholders)

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-filter-resources-based-on-values-from-a-properties-file.html?page=1