# inject value in property value using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to inject values dynamically into the contents of properties, as follows:

Properties file:

```
test.foo.sentence = Hello ..... I am ........ I work at .....
```

and when I call in a class like this:

```
@Value ("$ {test.foo.sentence {0} {1} {2}} ')
private String sentence;
```

Is it possible to do something like that to inject value from class in the "...."(blank space) in the properties value?

Comment: you want to inject an `List`? can you show some input and output example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot usage of placeholder in application properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273773/spring-boot-usage-of-placeholder-in-application-properties)