# spring boot application.properties value from bean data

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working with spring boot. I have properties defined in application.yml.

```
   spring:
     datasource:
       username: username
       password: password
```

username and password values are stored externally which program fetches during startup. let's say the bean which fetches them during startup is `dbConfig`
How can I inject values from `dbConfgig` to application.yml?

I am using spring-data-jpa autoconfigure which automatically connects to database at startup. I want these values to be loaded to application.yml before spring connects to database.

Comment: Do you mean placeholder? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273773/spring-boot-usage-of-placeholder-in-application-properties

Comment: yes something similar to this. but can I call a function in placeholder?

Comment: As I know, cannot call a function at application.yaml, why not set the value at your start script?@warrior107

Answer (score 0):

I think that first, you must create a thread to detect the change at your `db Config file` and then may you must re-init your bean (data source) to make your change effect.

See:
[how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean)

Comment: reloading bean is something I can work with. But the problem will be during startup the database connection will be made and it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to inject the user/password in `application.yml`. You can set them programmatically like this:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        
        // Take the values from external source, then set them
        dataSourceBuilder.username("username");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("password");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using spring-boot-cloud-gcp-sql-autoconfigure. This automatically creates a Datasource bean. It takes the username and password from application.yml

Comment: @warrior107 There is no such thing as `spring-boot-cloud-gcp-sql-autoconfigure`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try spring cloud to store properties. And you can then use with the help of placeholders.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/html/